# When using Pandas .groupby, why use .agg versus directly using the function eg .sum()

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

In Python, to obtain summaries by group, I use `groupby().agg(fx())`; eg `groupby('variable').agg('sum')`. What is the difference between that and directly using the function, eg; `groupby('variable').sum()` ?

Comment: You can aggregate different columns using different functions, or you can aggregate the same column using multiple functions.  It's very flexible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})
```

The primary benefit of using [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) is stated in [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

> Aggregate using **one or more operations** over the specified axis.

If you have separate operations that need to be applied to each individual column, `agg` takes a dictionary (or a function, string, or list of strings/functions) that allows you to create that mapping in a single statement.  So if you'd like the `sum` of column `a`, and the `mean` of column `b`:

```
df.agg({'a': 'sum', 'b': 'mean'})

a    6.0
b    5.0
dtype: float64
```

It also allows you to apply multiple operations to a single column in a single statement.  For example, to find the `sum`, `mean`, and `std` of column `a`:

```
df.agg({'a': ['sum', 'mean', 'std']})

        a
sum   6.0
mean  2.0
std   1.0
```

There's no difference in outcome when you use `agg` with a single operation. I'd argue that `df.agg('sum')` is less clear than `df.sum()`, but the results will be the same:

```
df.agg('sum')

a     6
b    15
dtype: int64

df.sum()

a     6
b    15
dtype: int64
```

The main benefit `agg` provides is the convenience of applying multiple operations.

Answer (score 2):

Using `groupby('variable').agg('sum')` is probably overkill if you are only passing one function.  It is usually used to aggregate multiple functions such as `.agg(['sum', 'mean'])`.

When just one function is passed, the results should be identical, albeit for a little more overhead with `.agg()` as it parses its arguments.

```
>>> from pandas.util import testing as tm
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed(444)

>>> df = tm.makeDataFrame()
>>> grp = df.groupby(df['A'] > 0)
>>> a = grp.agg('sum')
>>> b = grp.sum()
>>> tm.assert_frame_equal(a, b)
```

A typical use of `.agg()` with multiple functions looks like:

```
>>> grp[['A', 'C']].agg(('sum', 'mean'))
               A                   C          
             sum      mean       sum      mean
A                                             
False -16.111352 -0.805568  0.423394  0.021170
True    9.435939  0.943594  4.788035  0.478803
```